# Desktop Webkit vs iOS Webkit text rendering

Tags: ios, safari, webkit

Does Safari Webkit render type *exactly* the same in the OSX desktop version as it does in iOS?

For example if you had an element containing a block of text do the glyphs render the same or at a fractionally different width, so that accumulatively the text could end with a different number of lines?

Are there any other considerations eg anti-aliasing?

Answer (score 0):

The webkit on desktop and that on mobile does not render it exactly the same. For example, a div with horizontal scroll may show up with vertical and horizontal scroll in iOS. For further comparison, see this table: http://www.quirksmode.org/webkit.html

**Edit:** To completely answer your question, type does not render exactly the same on mobile and desktop. Even changing the font size causes the rendering to look different. So, no, the font will have pixel differences. http://blog.typekit.com/2011/01/26/css-properties-that-affect-type-rendering/

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link! I couldn't see information about type rendering though so I'll leave this question open a bit longer.